# Multiplying a 3D Vector by a scalar in main method

Tags: c++, vector

I'm very new to C++ and im trying to multiply a vector by a scalar.

The code in my vector3D.h file:

```
//multiply this vector by a scalar
Vector3D operator*(float num) const
{
    return Vector3D(x * num, y * num, z * num);
}
```

Main function:

```
int scalar = 2;
Vector3D*vector1 = new Vector3D(1,2,4);
cout << " Vector multiplcation by scalar ";
cout << vector1*scalar;
```

I understand this is completly wrong but I have no idea how I would use the function above.

The error given is expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type.

Thanks

Comment: Why is `vector1` a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HolyBlackCat has some good comments, and you should follow them. Here is a minimum working example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vector3D {
public:
    Vector3D(double x, double y, double z): x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    Vector3D operator*(double num) const {
        return Vector3D(x*num, y*num, z*num);
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << endl;
    }

private:
    double x, y, z;
};


int main() {
    int scalar = 2;
    Vector3D vector1(1, 2, 4);
    cout << "Vector multiplcation by scalar: ";
    Vector3D vector2 = vector1*scalar;
    vector2.print();
}
```

Notice the extra print() method. If you want to do something like cout << vector1*scalar, then you will also need to do some extra work to define how ostream handles Vector3D objects.

Comment: It is not incorrect to have the this pointer, but your are correct that it is not needed. I revised my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing dereferencing operator `*` before `vector1` in the expression. You need it because `vector1` is not a `Vector3D` itself, it's just a pointer.

Also, you should keed in mind that С++ is not like java. In your case `new` is completely redundand and unsafe (may lead to memory leaks if you forget to delete it). Here simple `Vector3D vector1(1, 2, 4);` is enough. Moreover, if you use this alternative, you don't need the extra `*`.